# Facebox inconvenience

Tags: facebox

So I'm having a problem implementing a date_picker into a facebox. In a normal view, the date_picker is placed perfectly and works great. However, when the view is placed into a facebox, the calendar is placed outside of the facebox, and switching between months and years is messed up.

This image is how I would like it to look in the facebox.

[image: screen]
<sub>(source: [drbones at students.cs.byu.edu](http://students.cs.byu.edu/%7Edrbones/Screenshot2.png))</sub>

However, this is how it looks like in the facebox.

[image: screen2]
<sub>(source: [drbones at students.cs.byu.edu](http://students.cs.byu.edu/%7Edrbones/Screenshot.png))</sub>

Thanks for any help

P.S.- I'm using the Code Igniter Framework if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely caused by the fact that facebox copies the html, thereby duplicating all element ids within. This is not standards compliant and causes incorrect binding of event listeners.

See [Bishoy Labib's writeup.](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/newsdetails.php?itemid=272)

[facebox](/questions/tagged/facebox)